# Смена цвета картинки при наведении на блок

Tags: html, css

Как сменить цвет картинки при наведении на кнопку. У меня цвет меняется только когда на картинку наводишь отдельно, а нужно чтобы когда полностью на блок.
Вот CSS:

```
.appao-btn {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 16px 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.appao-btn:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #0070D3;
}
.writeus img:hover {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: red;

}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="appao-btn writeus" href="#" style="margin-left: 160px;"><img src="assets/img/icons/icon5.svg">write us</a>
```

При наведении на блок, цвет `write us` меняется, но картинка рядом нет, только если на нее отдельно навести курсором. Как это решить? Спасибо.

Comment: Что вам мешает вместо изображения использовать background для тега `а` или прописать условие `.writeus a:hover img`?

Comment: @DaemonHK извините, можете на примере показать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```css
.appao-btn {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 16px 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.appao-btn:hover {
    background: #fff;
    /*border: 1px solid #fff; это здесь не нужно, границы уже есть такие*/
    color: #0070D3;
}
.writeus:hover img {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: red;

}
```

```html
<a class="appao-btn writeus" href="#" style="margin-left: 160px;"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/87/87390.svg">write us</a>
```

P.S. Сообщество, я в курсе, что картинку могут удалить, поделитесь, куда ее на стаке загружать(

Answer (score 0):

Поменять `.writeus img:hover` на `.writeus:hover img`

```css
.appao-btn {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 16px 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.appao-btn:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #0070D3;
}
.writeus:hover img {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: red;

}
```

```html
<a class="appao-btn writeus" href="#" style="margin-left: 160px;"><img src="assets/img/icons/icon5.svg">write us</a>
```